# Regular expression problem

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I have this question and no clue how to solve. Thanks for your help

I need to build the regular expression matching this language 
$$L=\{ 0^m~1^n | (m+n) \pmod 3 = 1 \}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

((000)*(111)*1) | ((000)*0(111)*) | ((000)*00(111)*11)

Comment: Thank you!
You realy helped me a lot